# Use variable value as name for another variable node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Using Discord.JS, I am trying to use the command's first argument (args[0]) to call another variable (summer). args[0] will be 'summer'. Let me put it this way, the command is for decorating channels, so when someone says `*decor summer` it calls the array with all the summer emojis.

Current code:

```js
let summer      = ['☀️', '', '️', '️', '⛱️', '']
let channelList = await message.guild.channels.fetch()
channelList.forEach(element => {
  if (element.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT' || element.type !== 'GUILD_VOICE') return

  if (!element.permissionsFor(message.client.user.id).has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return

  //args[0] will be 'summer,' and I want it to call the summer array of emojis showed above.
  let randomemoji = [args[0]][Math.floor(Math.random() * [args[0]].length)] //this is my attempt at trying to call the summer array
  console.log(randomemoji)
});
```

Is there some way I can get it to call the summer (or any other array with the same name as the value of args[0]) array? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put `summer` in an Object and refer to it in bracket notation?

```
let seasons      = {
                       summer: ['☀️', '', '️', '️', '⛱️', ''],
                       /* other seasons here */
                   };
let channelList = await message.guild.channels.fetch()
channelList.forEach(element => {
  if (element.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT' || element.type !== 'GUILD_VOICE') return

  if (!element.permissionsFor(message.client.user.id).has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return

  //args[0] will be 'summer,' and I want it to call the summer array of emojis showed above.
  let randomemoji = seasons[args[0]][Math.floor(Math.random() * [args[0]].length)] //this is my attempt at trying to call the summer array
  console.log(randomemoji)
});
```

Comment: A combination of this and fixing my if statements fixed it, sorry about that, should have seen it.